# Using Blaze.render inside of a bootbox dialog - getting weird bug

Tags: javascript, meteor, dialog, meteor-blaze, bootbox

So I have a bootbox dialog that I need to have a button on that will create another bootbox dialog box. My issue is though the second bootbox dialog has a lot of javascript code so I was trying to use

```
Blaze.render Template.templateName, $('#dialogNode')[0]
```

to create the second dialog box, but this causes the second dialog box to have the same styling width as the first and disabling all buttons to be pressed (must hit esc twice to close both dialogs at the same time. If I try to render the second dialog box by following the Custom HTML example on http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html there is no issue, but I need to be able to use Blaze.render to use a certain template with its js code. Any thoughts about the error I am having? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue everyone! Both of my dialog boxes were called with the same id #dialogNode, so I just changed one of them!